# AtTask API get assigned users

Tags: api, attask

We have multiple people assigned to a single ticket but when using the assignedToID field, it just returns the first user?.. Why is it not returning an array of user ids?

I know this is off-topic but is it possible to get user's name also and not just id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of users you can user  assignmentsListString
to pull user names instead of IDs you should be able to use
assignedTo:name

example

```
/attask/api/v4.0/task/54d25b43005a2117e6c2d674b932a666?fields=assignmentsListString,assignedTo:name
```